# How can I redirect an domain from http to https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have an hosting with ipage and I have 5 domains on this hosting. My master domain is called eroups.com, and I already bought ssl for it but when I ask my hosting support to redirect it from `http` to `https` all my domains are redirecting to `https` and I don't have ssl for them yet.

And I make for this other each domain folder as redirect into this folder please if some one know how to fix that I just need to redirect eroups.com to `https` only and other same like `http`.

My domains are:

- eroups.com (this is the master and have ssl)
- imolawigs.com
- imolagallery.com
- kittyshoping.com
- kittywedding.com

Please someone write the code for me I can't understand how to make that by myself and support didn't understand anything also.

Comment: Does this help? The second option with plugin may be easier. https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/migrate-wordpress-from-http-to-https/

Answer (score 1):

so basically there are 4 main steps:

1. update the url in your database http://yourdomain.net -> https://yourdomain.net
2. set a http to https redirect in your .htaccess file
3. check for any hardcoded http://yourdomain.net occurrences in the source files of your theme
4. check for external resources which are loaded via http://.... (fonts, images, ...) and correct them to https://

Do you have some programming skills? Then I could sent you the tools and code snippets which you can use to accomplish the transition from http to https.

Unfortunately this process can not be automated by a plugin.

Cheers, Dominik

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I have a little skill in prgraming please send me the code for .htaccess file and i will put it into htaccses and check my domins also to fix any issue

Comment: I'll add the code to my answer .. .but if you don't change the db entries, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to code/touch your servers, you can achieve this without writing any code only by using a CDN for example if using Cloudflare: [How do I redirect all visitors to HTTPS/SSL?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-).

Comment: @senior yes, check https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Step-2-Create-a-Cloudflare-account-and-add-a-website